# Rotate some elements in an ellipse path

Tags: processing, ellipse

I am trying to make some objects, say 12, to rotate in an ellipse path continuously in Processing. I got a sketch which does rotation in a circle and I want to make it to rotate in a ellipse. I have some pointer from processing forum but the code from the pointer is different from the code that I posted and I couldn't understand yet (weak in trigonometry).

I googled a bit and found a post trying to achieve this with this algorithm:

> You need to define your ellipse with a few parameters:
>
> ```
> x, y: center of the ellipse
> a, b: semimajor and semiminor axes
> ```
>
> If you want to move on the elipses this means that you change the
>   angle between the major axes and your position on the ellipse. Lets
>   call this angle alpha.
>
> Your position (X,Y) is:
>
> ```
> X = x + (a * Math.cos(alpha));
> Y = y + (b * Math.sin(alpha));
> ```
>
> In order to move left or right you need to increase/decrease alpha and
>   then recalculate your position. Source:
>   http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/27620/move-object-allong-an-ellipsoid-path.html

How do I integrate it into my sketch? Thank you.

Here's my sketch:

```java
void setup()
{
    size(1024, 768);
    textFont(createFont("Arial", 30));
}

void draw()
{
    background(0);
    stroke(255);

    int cx = 500;
    int cy = 350;
    int r = 300; //radius of the circle
    float t = millis()/4000.0f; //increase to slow down the movement

    ellipse(cx, cy, 5, 5);

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 12; i++) {
        t = t + 100;
        int x = (int)(cx + r * cos(t));
        int y = (int)(cy + r * sin(t));

        line(cx, cy, x, y);
        textSize(30);
        text(i, x, y);

        if (i == 10) {
            textSize(15);
            text("x: " + x + " y: " + y, x - 50, y - 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
int r = 300; //radius of the circle
```

with

```
int a = 350; // major axis of ellipse
int b = 250; // minor axis of ellipse
```

and replace

```
int x = (int)(cx + r * cos(t));
int y = (int)(cy + r * sin(t));
```

with

```
int x = (int)(cx + a * cos(t));
int y = (int)(cy + b * sin(t));
```